# What could make a connection.send() block ? (from conn1, conn2 = multiprocessing.Pipe() )

Tags: python, multiprocessing, pipe

I am debugging application that gather information from 2 sensors : a webcam and a microphone.

The general architecture is quite simple :

- the main process sends messages (start, stop, get_data) via pipes to the child processes (one for each).
- child processes gather the data and send it to the main process

Child & main processes are in infinite loops to process commands (the main process from the user, the child process from the main process).

It globally works but I have trouble stopping the child processes.

I have logged the code and it seems to happen 2 things :

1. The 'stop' message is sent but doesn't get through the pipe.
2. The child process continue to send data and the conn.send(data) blocks.

The behavior is clearly linked to the state of the connection, as child processes that send nothing back don't have this behavior. Still, I don't see how to debug/modify the current architecture which seems reasonnable.

So, what cause this blocking behavior and how to avoid it ?

This is the code which is executed for each iteration of the infinite loop in the child process :

```
    def do(self):
        while self.cnx.poll():
            msg = self.cnx.recv()
            self.queue.append(msg)
        #==
        if not self.queue:
            func_name = 'default_action'
            self.queue.append([func_name, ])
        #==
        msg             = self.queue.pop()
        func_name, args = msg[0], msg[1:]
        #==
        res = self.target.__getattribute__(func_name)(*args)
        #==
        running = func_name != 'stop'
        #==
        if res and self.send:
            assert running
            self.output_queue.append(res[0])
        if self.output_queue and running:
            self.cnx.send(self.output_queue.popleft())
        #==
        return running
```

**update** : it seems that the Pipe cannot be written simultaneously on both end. It works if change the last few lines of the above code to :

```
        if self.output_queue and running:
            if not self.cnx.poll(): 
                self.cnx.send(self.output_queue.popleft())
```

The question stays open though as Pipe are documented as full duplex by default and this behavior is not documented at all. I must have misunderstood something. Please, enlight me!

**update 2** : just to be clear, no connection is closed during in this situation. To describe the sequence of events :

- the main process sends a messsage ("stop") (it empties the connection before sending the message)
- the main process enter an (infinite) loop that stops when the child process is terminated.
- meanwhile, the child process is blocked in the send and never gets the message.

Comment: Could you post your code? Otherwise, its hard to solve your problem.

Comment: I have added the code of the child process. (The parent is just sending the message).

Comment: What OS are you running on? `multiprocessing.Pipe` is implemented rather differently (and with some different semantics, I think) on Windows.

Comment: Mainly on Ubuntu, but IIRC the behavior is the same on windows.

Comment: Isn't the assert raising an exception? This could close all connections. Can you tell what's the last operation done at the client-side?

Comment: No, the assert is not triggered. If we consider the main process, as the client and the sensors as servers, the last action done by the client is sending the "stop" message but the last executed message is "start". Between the two, the servers starts to send (big) datum to the client and, after a while seems stuck in the sending. Some buffer seems to be full and it perturbates the reception somehow.

Answer (score 5):

A full duplex `multiprocessing.Pipe` is implemented as `socketpair()`.  Calling `.send` can block for all the normal reasons when talking to a socket.  Based on your description I think it's likely that the reader of your `Pipe` has quit reading and data has built up in the buffers in the kernel to the point where your `.send` blocks.

If you explicitly `.close` the receiving side you'll probably get some kind of error (although possibly `SIGPIPE` as well, not sure) when you try to `.send`.  If your receiving connection was going out of scope this would probably happen automatically.  You may be able to fix the problem by just being more careful not to store references (direct or indirect) to the receiving side so it gets deallocated when that thread goes away.

Trivial demo of blocking `.send`:

```
import multiprocessing

a, b = multiprocessing.Pipe()

while True:
    print "send!"
    a.send("hello world")
```

Now note that after a while it quits printing "send!"

Comment: I considered that but both the receiver and the sender are still alive, and no connection is closed. I updated the main text.